# Why I Can't assign value to variable in react through function handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

```
function App() {
  
  var name="liaqat";
  
  function changeMe()
  {
    // here i am trying to change this particular variable or state 
    name="asif";
  }


  return (
    <div>
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <button onClick={changeMe}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> I can do this by using hooks, but the above code doesn't work by using just handler function?

Comment: It does work. It just doesn't behave the way you expect it to. It behaves to way React expects it to since React is in control. Either remove React and do it your way, or use React and do it React's way.

Comment: Directly changing the value of a variable inside of a react component does not trigger a rerender. You have to use the setState dispatcher provided by [`useState()`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState) to update the value and rerender your content correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value as `name = "asif"` to `name` variable. But view will not update  due to no re-render hence `name` is not either a "state" or "prop".

```
function App() {
  var name = "liaqat";

  function changeMe() {
    name = "asif";
    console.log(name); // print asif 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button onClick={changeMe}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In below example used another state variable `reRender` for re-render purpose. But here `name` variable reassign `name="liaqat"` initial value on every re-render. So view shows same value as "liaqat".

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  var name = "liaqat";
  const [reRender, setReRender] = useState(false);

  function changeMe() {
    name = "asif";
    console.log(name); // print: asif
    setReRender(true);
  }

  console.log(name, reRender); 
  // print on component mount: liaqat false
  // print on component re-render: liaqat true
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button onClick={changeMe}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For to update the view use either `name` variable as a "state" or "prop". In below example when changing `name` state trigger a re render which leads to update the view.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("liaqat");

  function changeMe() {
    setName("asif");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button onClick={changeMe}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```